# Bug in autocomplete MUI component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm using t`his component and it has a problem setting the value in the input. Instead of setting the value it receives from the combo, it is setting the label.

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { Combo } from "types/combo";
import { Form } from "components/Form";

interface InputProps {
      name: string;
      options: Combo[];
      onChange?: (e: any) => void;
}

export function AutoComplete(props: InputProps) {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={props.name}
      render={({ field }: any) => (
        <>
          <Autocomplete
            value={props.options.find((option: Combo) => option.value === field.value) || null}
            onChange={(_, option: any) => {
              field.onChange(option ? option.value : null);
              props.onChange ? props.onChange(option ? option.value : null) : "";
            }}
            disablePortal
            size="small"
            options={props.options}
            getOptionLabel={(option: Combo): string => option.label}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option: Combo, value: any) => option.value === value}
            renderInput={(params: any) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                inputRef={params.inputRef} // Passar a referência do input para o Autocomplete
                name={props.name}
              />
            )}
          />
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

I've tried to change the find value and I still couldn't. I wanted to make the value I get from the combo be the value of my input.